# Off selected event handler from attached event list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where from third party component, I get multiple attached event to a single element.

The simulation is something like following.

```
$('.myLink').on('click',function(){alert('1')})
$('.myLink').on('click',function(){alert('2')})
$('.myLink').on('click',function(){alert('3')})
```

And, I can see list of attached events using,

```
$._data( $('.myLink'), "events"))
```

Now, i just want to off second event handler using index.
i.e. `alert('2')`

Please let me know the method to deal with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any way to refer to the event or its handler other than the code that is inside its handler?

Comment: No, it is from third party. So, i don't have any control on it.

Comment: you could always remove all three then add the other 2 back if worse comes to worse

Comment: Hmm.. that option is at last available and seems work for me. but there is lots of manual effort and also hard to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$._data($('.myLink')[0], "events").click[1].handler()
```

<kbd>[Fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/D6XcU/)</kbd>

To remove the event say:

```
$('.myLink').off("click", $._data($('.myLink')[0], "events").click[1].handler)
```

Comment: Yes, I want to off this handler. Can you please tell me how?

Comment: @DipalMehta: Ah, now I get what you mean by *off*. I thought you meant off it as in *fire off* ;P

Comment: @DipalMehta: You are welcome. I did not get what you asked at first, but now it makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myLink').on('click',function(){alert('1')})
$('.myLink').on('click',function(){alert('2')})
$('.myLink').on('click',function(){alert('3')})
//fetch all event attached to myLink
var a=$._data( $('.myLink')[0], "events") ;  
//call second event alert(2)
 a.click[1].handler();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9RMn5/

Comment: Yes, I want to off this handler. Can you please tell me how?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?